# A first order non-linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve the first order non-linear ordinary differential equation , 
$$y^3=xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + x^4 \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2$$

Comment: It's a quadratic in the derivative, so you could start by solving the quadratic. Might not work, but worth a try.

Comment: Just tried, variables don't separate immediately but there may be another technique

Comment: The Maple command $$infolevel[dsolve]:=5:dsolve(y(x)^3 = x*y(x)^2*(diff(y(x), x))+x^4*(diff(y(x), x))^2) $$ produces $$y \left( x \right) =-4\,{x}^{2},y \left( x \right) ={\it WeierstrassP} \left( -1/2\,{\frac {\sqrt [3]{
2}}{x}}+{\it \_C1},0,0 \right) {2}^{2/3}
 ,$$ commenting Methods for first order ODEs:
   *** Sublevel 2 ***
   Methods for first order ODEs:
   -> Solving 1st order ODE of high degree, 1st attempt
   trying 1st order WeierstrassP solution for high degree ODE
   <- 1st_order WeierstrassP successful

Comment: @user64494, If the elliptic invariants are both zero the Weierstrass differential equation has elementary solutions, in fact your solution simplifies (simply type simplify in Maple) and you get: $$y \left( x \right) =4\,{\frac {{x}^{2}{\it WeierstrassP} \left( 1,0,0
 \right) {2}^{2/3}}{ \left( \sqrt [3]{2}-2\,{\it \_C1}\,x \right) ^{2}
}}
$$, however I can't seem to verify your solution (simplified or otherwise) unless I'm typing it in wrong?

Comment: @ Graham Heskesh: The  answer with  WeierstrassP is a bug of Maple. I submitted it in Maplesoft. They made a promise to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly we note that: $$y(x)=0 \tag{Solution 1}$$ is a solution, hereafter we take $y(x)\ne0$.
Substitute: $$y(x)=\dfrac{1}{h(x)}$$ into:$$ y \left( x \right)   ^{3}=x  y \left( x \right) 
  ^{2}{\frac {d}{dx}}y \left( x \right) +{x}^{4} \left( {\frac 
{d}{dx}}y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}\tag{1}$$
to get:
$$\begin{align}
h \left( x \right) &=-x{\frac {d}{dx}}h \left( x \right) +{x}^{4}
 \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}h \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2} \\
h \left( x \right) +\dfrac{1}{4x^2}&={x}^{4} \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}h
 \left( x \right) -\dfrac{1}{2x^3} \right) ^{2}\\ 
&={x}^{4} \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}\left(h
 \left( x \right) +\dfrac{1}{4x^2}\right) \right) ^{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
and we see that:
\begin{align} h(x)&=-\dfrac{1}{4x^2}\\
y(x)&=-4x^2 \tag{Solution 2}\end{align}
is a solution (as found by @Daniel Littlewood and @user64494). Note: in $(2)$ we divided by $1/h(x)^4$ under the assumption it was not zero everywhere, if it were we would recover $\text{Solution 1}$. Then substitute:
$$h(x)=g \left( x \right) -\dfrac{1}{4x^2}$$
into $(2)$ to get:
$$g \left( x \right) ={x}^{4} \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}g \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\tag{3}$$
and change the variable to $x=\dfrac{1}{\xi}$ in $(3)$ and write $g(x)=f(x)^2$ to get:
\begin{align}g \left( \xi \right) &=\left( {\frac {d}{d\xi}}g \left( \xi \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\\ 
f\left( \xi \right)^2 &=4f\left( \xi \right)^2\left( {\frac {d}{d\xi}}f\left( \xi \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\tag{4}\end{align}
we then divide by $f(\xi)^2$ under the assumption it is not zero everywhere, if it were we would recover $\text{Solution 2}$, and we have:
\begin{align} {\frac {d}{d\xi}}f \left( \xi \right)&=\pm\dfrac{1}{2}\\
f \left( \xi \right)&=C\pm\dfrac{\xi}{2} \tag{5}\end{align}
but by noting that $g=f^2$ we can encompass either sign possibility in the arbitrary constant $C$ and write:
$$\begin{align}
g(\xi)&=\left(C+\dfrac{\xi}{2}\right)^2 \\
g(x)&=\left(C+\dfrac{1}{2x}\right)^2\tag{6}
\end{align}$$
Working backwards we then have:
$$y \left( x \right) ={\frac {1}{\left(\dfrac{C}{2}\right)^2 +\left(\dfrac{C}{2}\right)\dfrac{1}{x}}}. \tag{7}$$
To fix the constant in $(7)$ we find that the starting value is useless because, irrespective of $C$:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}y(x)=0$$
but we can use the starting value of the derivative (Neumann boundary condition) to find that:
$$C=\dfrac{2}{y'(0)}$$
$$y \left( x \right) ={\frac {y'(0)^2}{1 +y'(0)\dfrac{1}{x}}}={\frac {xy'(0)^2}{x +y'(0)}} \tag{Solution 3}$$
so this solution is bilinear in $x$. We also note that $\text{Solution 1}$ is encompassed in $\text{Solution 3}$ but $\text{Solution 2}$ is distinct.

Comment: Wolframalpha managed to miss it as well, which confused me.

Comment: @Graham Hesketh: In writing $y(x)=\frac {1}{h(x)}$ , we deliberately assume $y(x)≠0$ , but $y(x)=0$ is indeed a solution of the original equation $y^3=xy^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + x^4 \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2 $ , I think another similar loophole is the reasom for missing out $y=-4x^2$

Comment: @Graham Hesketh:$g \left( x \right) ={x}^{4} \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}g \left( x \right) \right) ^{2}$ ,from this we get $4g(x)=\Big(c- \frac{1}{x}\Big)^2$ by considering $ \frac {d\Big(g(x)\Big)}{\sqrt{g(x)}} = \frac {dx}{x^2}$ and we also get $4g(x)=\Big(c+ \frac {1}{x}\Big)^2$  by considering $\frac {d\Big(g(x)\Big)}{\sqrt{g(x)}} = -\frac {dx}{x^2}$ ,in both these cases we assume  $g(x)≠0$ , $g(x)=0$ gives $h(x)=-\dfrac{1}{4x^2}$ that is $y(x)=-4x^2$

Comment: @Souvik Dey, cheers I updated. I had glossed over the y=0 solution to move on to something more "interesting" :), but I couldn't see the $-4x^2$ I have found it now...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a general solution, but I've found a particular one:

If $y$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then the LHS has degree $3k$, the first term on the RHS has degree $3k$ and the second term has degree $2k+2$. If the two sides are identical, we require $2k+2\le3k$, so $k\ge2$, with equality at $k=2$. If we check, say, $y=ax^{2}$, we get
$$a^{3}x^{6}=2a^{3}x^{6}+4a^{2}x^{6}$$
So $a^{3}=-4a^{2}$, giving $a=0$ (trivial) or $a=-4$, so $y=-4x^{2}$. Using Wolfram Alpha, I have verified that this is the only solution of degree $\le 4$.

Answer (score 2):

These are all the solutions of this ODE, obtained using the Maple computer algebra system, and they are all verifiable (I would like to post with format, but not having 10 points the system does not allow me to upload an image, so it goes here in ascii):

Your equation - written in Maple syntax:

> ode := y(x)^3-x*y(x)^2*(diff(y(x), x))-x^4*(diff(y(x), x))^2 = 0:

Five explicit solutions:

> sol := dsolve(ode, Lie); # use Lie symmetry methods

```
                         / (1/2)          \      2  
               2         \2      _C1 - 2 x/ x _C1   
    y(x) = -4 x , y(x) = -------------------------, 
                                /   2      2\       
                              2 \_C1  - 2 x /       

               / (1/2)          \      2  
               \2      _C1 + 2 x/ x _C1   
      y(x) = - -------------------------, 
                      /   2      2\       
                    2 \_C1  - 2 x /       

                   / (1/2)          2  \  
               2 x \2      _C1 - _C1  x/  
      y(x) = - -------------------------, 
                     2 /   2  2    \      
                  _C1  \_C1  x  - 2/      

                 / (1/2)          2  \
             2 x \2      _C1 + _C1  x/
      y(x) = -------------------------
                   2 /   2  2    \    
                _C1  \_C1  x  - 2/
```

where _C1 is an arbitarry constant. These five solutions verify OK; in Maple you test that these ODE solutions cancel the given ODE in this way:

> map(odetest, [sol], ode);

```
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To understand from where are these five solutions coming, you can always solve the equation implicitly, and you see three solutions, two of which are quadratic in y

> sol := dsolve(ode, Lie, implicit);

```
         2
```

y(x) = -4 x ,

```
                                         (1/2)            
             2        /    2      2     \                 
         y(x)    y(x) \y(x)  + 4 x  y(x)/                 
2 y(x) + ----- + ----------------------------- - _C1 = 0, 
           2                   2                          
          x                   x                           

                               (1/2)          
            /    2      2     \               
 2     1    \y(x)  + 4 x  y(x)/               
---- + -- + ------------------------ - _C1 = 0
y(x)    2                 2                   
       x            y(x) x
```

To understand why three solutions, note that the ODE is nonlinear in the highest derivative y' and so there are singular cases. In the Maple system you compute the essential singular cases in this way:

> PDEtools:-casesplit(ode, singsol = essential);

```
                                3         2 / d      \    
                        2   y(x)  - x y(x)  |--- y(x)|  
              / d      \                    \ dx     /  
              |--- y(x)|  = --------------------------, 
              \ dx     /                 4              
                                        x               

                           2
                y(x) = -4 x
```

The meaning of this result is, basically, that there is a singular solution 
                                   2
                           y = -4 x

that is not a particular case of the solutions of y'^2 = (y^3 - x y' y^2)/(x^4); in turn the latter, quadratic in y' leads to two solutions, each of them quadratic in y, shown above as the output of dsolve(ode, implicit)

Edgardo S. Cheb-Terrab

Comment: (+1) now you can upload! :) This seems interesting I'd like to understand where these solutions are coming from I can't quite understand it from this syntax, perhaps if you find the time you could latex them?

Comment: On closer inspection there is some redundancy in these solutions, take the first one for example:$$y \left( x \right) ={\frac { \left( \sqrt {2}C-2\,x \right) x{C}^{2}}{
2\,{C}^{2}-4\,{x}^{2}}}={\frac {x{C}^{2}}{\sqrt {2}C+2\,x}}={\frac {xy'(0)^2}{x +y'(0)}} $$ so by factoring the quadratic in the numerator I think you can write all four similar cases as that one, by encompassing sign differences in the constant. (+1) anyway because it is interesting to see how to get maple to spit them out, just need to simplify the result.